# Swift - Complete action after NSURLSession resumes

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to complet an an action after the URLSession resumes.

So I am downloading several images from my server with the url, which all works good. But now I am trying to save those images to the disk after I have finished downloading them.

**Problem**

Now I can save them inside the same query while downloading them but I would prefer not too as it makes my query slower.

So I have added a completion handler to my func with the query, but when I save the images to the disk in that block it works but I cannot do anything with my screen as the query has not resumed yet it is blocked from touches I guess...

Now I would like to be able to call my func to save the images to the disk straight after the query has been resumed.... Anyone have any idea?

If someone needs more explanation or to see code just drop a comment below

Many thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

**Code for downloading**

```
func loadPosts(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

        pageNumber = 1
        appDelegate.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(true)

        let id = user!["id"] as! String
        let url = URL(string: "http://************/Files/Posts.php")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let body = "id=\(id)&caption=&uuid=&page="
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                if error == nil {

                    let oldImageArray = self.cellContentArray
                    self.cellContentArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)


                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                         guard let parseJSON = json else {
                            print("Error while parsing")
                            return
                        }
                        guard let posts = parseJSON["Posts"] as? [AnyObject] else {
                            print("Error while parseJSONing")
                           return
                        }
                        for element in posts {
                            // here I download the stuff and it to my Array, too long and no point to show here

                        }

                        let oldImageSet = Set(oldImageArray.map({return $0.uuid}))
                        let newImageSet = Set(self.cellContentArray.map({return $0.uuid}))
                        let addedImages = newImageSet.subtracting(oldImageSet)
                        let addedImageSections = Array(addedImages).map{ self.cellContentArray.map({return $0.uuid}).index(of: $0)! }
                        let addedImageIndexSet = IndexSet(addedImageSections)
                        let removedImages = oldImageSet.subtracting(newImageSet)
                        let removedImageSections = Array(removedImages).map{ oldImageArray.map({return $0.uuid}).index(of: $0)! }
                        let removedImageIndexSet = IndexSet(removedImageSections)


                        if !addedImageIndexSet.isEmpty {
                            if oldImageArray.count >= 5 {
                            self.lastUUIDImage = oldImageArray[4].uuid
                            } else {

                            }
                            self.coreDataShit()
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                            print(placeholderImage.count)
                            if placeholderImage.count > 5 {
                                placeholderImage.removeFirst(placeholderImage.count - 5)
                            }
                            print("finished")
                            self.customView.isHidden = true
                            if posts.count >= 5 {
                                self.tableView.addInfiniteScroll { [weak self] (scrollView) -> Void in
                                    self?.loadMore()
                                }}
                            self.activityView.stopAnimating()
                            self.internetView.removeFromSuperview()



                          self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                            if !addedImageIndexSet.isEmpty {
                                self.tableView.insertSections(addedImageIndexSet, with: .top)
                            }
                            if !removedImageIndexSet.isEmpty {
                                self.tableView.deleteSections(removedImageIndexSet, with: .bottom)
                            }
                            self.tableView.endUpdates()
                            self.tableView.finishInfiniteScroll()
                            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
                            appDelegate.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(false)
                            completionHandler(true)

                       }
                    } catch {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.removeInfiniteScroll()
                            self.customView.isHidden = false
                            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }


                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let message = error!.localizedDescription
                        appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: smoothRedColor)
                    })
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()

    }
```

**Saving Image**

```
   self.loadPosts(completionHandler: { (true) in
                print("completion")

                let sections = self.tableView.numberOfSections
                for i in 0..<sections {
                    self.rows += self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i)
                }

                print(self.rows)

                if self.rows <= 5 {
                    print("less than 5")
                    print(self.rows)
                    var i = 0

                    for element in self.cellContentArray {

                        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
                        let dirPath = "\(path)/images"
                        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath)
                        let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent("\(element.uuid).jpg")?.path
                        let fileManager = FileManager.default
                        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath!) {
                            print("File exsists")

                        } else {
                            print("File doesn't exsist")
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                let url = NSURL(string: element.fullImage!)! // convert path str to url
                                let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) // get data via url and assigned imageData
                                let imageName = element.uuid
                                let saveImages = FileSaveHelper(fileName: imageName, fileExtension: .JPG, subDirectory: "images", directory: .documentDirectory)
                                do {
                                    guard let image = UIImage.sd_image(with: imageData as Data!) else {
                                        print("Error getting image")
                                        return
                                    }
                                    try saveImages.saveFile(image: image)
                                    self.saveNewImagePath(imageLink: imageName, uuid: imageName)
                                    self.removeImage(itemName: "file\(i)", fileExtension: "jpg")
                                    self.removeImage(itemName: self.lastUUIDImage, fileExtension: "jpg")

                                    i += 1

                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

            })
```

**Image in tableView Cell**

```
 self.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: content.fullImage!), placeholderImage: placeHolder, options: .retryFailed) { (image:UIImage?, error:Error?, cached:SDImageCacheType, url:URL?) in

           }
```

Comment: If you are downloading your images in main thread then it will surely block your UI. Download and save images asynchronously then your UI will not be blocked.

Comment: Oh so the dispatch async is causing the problem? is that not neccessary?

Comment: @Rajat I have this inside the nsurl request DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
             and then this when I update the tableView DispatchQueue.main.async{

Comment: Edit your question and add your code of downloading and saving of image, that will be helpful.

Comment: @Rajat Updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code of saving image this line of code is blocking you UI

```
let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) // get data via url and assigned imageData
```

This is not proper way to download image from server, you should download image asynchronously using `URLSession`

Comment: But I am only getting the link not that actuall image in my query, so I do need to download it anyway

Comment: Well i am only downloading the image there to save it to the device system. I am actually downloading the image in the cell using sdwebimage, but that only downloads the image when the cell is visible, and I'd like to be able to save the images to device without having to scroll through the cells? any idea of another solution?

Comment: In this case also you are downloading your image twice ;) , well I would like to mention you that SDWebImage also manage the cache of downloaded images and it also save the image to FileManager, I would suggest you to use SDWebManager to download your image.

Comment: Well I am yes, but as I mentioned I am downloading only when the cell becomes visual. Do you know a way to download all the images even if the cells are not visual?

Comment: Let the code of your table view cell remain as it is and use SDWebImageManager to download your image that will download your image asynchronously, go through this link it will be helpful - https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/Docs/HowToUse.md

Comment: I already am, I'll add my tableView cell code so you can see...But how should I save it to the disk from there?

Comment: I am not talking to save image in your cellForRow, I am telling you to use sdwebimagemanager in place of contentsOfUrl (which I have mentioned in my answer) to download image and in the completion handler of that save your image to disk.

Comment: Sorry about that you were right! Thanks alot... Couldn't understand what you meant, too much banging my head over this issue I can't understand anything!! +1!